What's the difference between Azure data lake gen 2 delta format vs delta lake?
I'm new to Azure synapse analytics and fabric.
I know there is Azure data lake gen 2 format like parquet and delta.
Is the delta format the same as Azure delta lake?

Azure Data Lake Gen 2 (ADLG2) isn't a file format like Delta or Parquet. ADLG2 is a service built on the Azure blob service. It is however unlike standard bolob (Gen 1) optimised for Data Lake workloads, and has better scalability, a hierarchical directory structure, and an improved security model. OneLake in Fabric, is based on ADLG2. You can implement a Delta Lake/Data Lakehouse on ADLG2, it is designed to be used in that way. A Delta Lake is just an approach for the Lakehouse to be organised and used. It doesn't matter which blob staorage type it can go on, like the AWS and GCP ones.
The Delta format is the same across the MS services such as Synapse and Fabric, and is the implementation of the open source Delta standard, so is transportable and usable across other none Azure services that can access it.
